# Curve shortening flow and strong maximum principle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am in particular uncertain about how the strong maximum principle is used in the argument below. Could someone please clarify  and add more detailed explanations. Thanks

So assume we have a regular embedded curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose endpoints are on the boundary of a closed convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.Furthermore assume it satisfies the curve shortening flow

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\gamma=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\gamma$$ If any part of the curve besides the endpoints touches the boundary of the convex subset, then by the strong maximum principle it follows that the flow makes the curve so that it no longer touches the boundary besides the endpoints for $t>0$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the phrase "curve automatically flows the curve."  What is the equation of the curve shortening flow?

Comment: I hope its clearer now. If not I'll add more details.

Comment: It is clear now.  Thank you.

Comment: Is there some additional hypothesis that the curve lies in the closed convex set, and that at least one point of the curve lies in the interior of the set?  As it is, I can take both the curve and the set to be the same straight line segments, and this gives a counterexample.

Comment: Whereas with this additional hypothesis, you can prove the statement by applying the maximal principle to $v \cdot \gamma$ for $v$ a non-zero vector.

Comment: We can assume that the endpoints of the curve is different.

Comment: But my proposed counterexample has endpoints that are different.

Comment: Okay then I think that the author omitted some details. His part of the proof must have also included the additional assumption that not all of the curve lies on the boundary.

Comment: And that the curve lies in the closed convex set.  Suppose that the closed set is a ball, and that the curve has endpoints on opposite ends of the closed set, but otherwise the curve stays outside the ball.  Then as $t\to\infty$, the curve converges to the straight line segment, and this is inside the closed ball.  So for some values of $t$, non-endpoints of the curve must lie on the boundary.

Comment: I think I understand it better now. Thanks Stephen.